# Redirecting http request using custom Reverse Proxy controller in java

Tags: java, angularjs, controller, client-server, reverse-proxy

I want to fetch data from different servers according to client id.

PS: everything is running on https, stackoverflow does not allow me to put more then 2 links, thats why I removed https part.

Let say, My proxy controller server is running on - 192.168.2.0:8080

I have multiple servers, let say server A on 192.168.2.20:8080 and server B on 192.168.2.30:8080.

If, my user aaa is hitting on proxy controller it should get response from server A, if user bbb is hitting on proxy server it should get response from server B.

eg. 192.168.2.0:8080/api/aaa/ui/index.html should actually call 192.168.2.20:8080/ui/index.html and client should get response.

Same for bbb user, in that case response should come from 192.168.2.30:8080/ui/index.html.

This use case is working for static content, but not for dynamic contents. I am not able to get dynamic data from the server.

I guess internally my server is giving me

Code on my controller.
Controller

This handles the URL and invoke this function.
it will take a URL like, http://localhost:8080/userId/ui/index.html
and calls a server according to the userId, UserId can be aaa or bbb.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}/**", method= RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String HTTPControllerEntry(@PathVariable("userId") String userId,HttpServletRequest request){
String urlEndSubstring = (String)request.getAttribute(
HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
int index = urlEndSubstring.indexOf('/',1 + urlEndSubstring.indexOf('/'));
urlEndSubstring = urlEndSubstring.substring(index+1);
String URL = userId+urlEndSubstring;
String response=httpRedirectionService.RedirectHttpUrl(userId, urlEndSubstring);
return response;
}
```

This function will get the prefix of the URL on the bases of userId and genrate the full URL with the specific ipaddress of the user.

```
@Override
public String RedirectHttpUrl(String userId, String urlEndSubstring) {
UserConnectionProperties ucP = new UserConnectionProperties();
String urlPrefix= ucP.readUserConnectionProperty(userId);
String URL = urlPrefix+urlEndSubstring;
return callURL(URL);
}
```

This function just get the http request and return it back to the controller. Controller will be returning back to the client.

```
private String callURL(String httpURL) {
System.out.println("Requeted URL: " + httpURL);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
URLConnection urlConn = null;
InputStreamReader in = null;
try {
URL url = new URL(httpURL);
urlConn = url.openConnection();
if (urlConn != null)
urlConn.setReadTimeout(60 * 1000);
if (urlConn != null && urlConn.getInputStream() != null) {
in = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream(),
Charset.defaultCharset());
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(in);
if (bufferedReader != null) {
int cp;
while ((cp = bufferedReader.read()) != -1) {
sb.append((char) cp);
}
bufferedReader.close();
}
}
in.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(("Exception while calling URL:"+ httpURL +" "+e+"\n"));
}

return sb.toString();
}
```

This will give the ipaddress of the internal server acccording to the userId

```
public String readUserConnectionProperty(String key){
Properties prop = loadPropertyfile();
return prop.getProperty(key);
}
```

To load the property file.

```
private Properties loadPropertyfile(){
Properties props = new Properties();
InputStream is = null;
try {
File f = new File("userConnection.properties");
is = new FileInputStream(f);
}
catch (Exception e){
is = null;
}

try {
if ( is == null ) {
is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("userConnection.properties");
}
if(is!=null){
props.load( is );
}
else {
throw new FileNotFoundException("property file userConnection not found in class path");
}
}
catch ( Exception e ) { }
return props;
}
```

userConnection.properties

```
aaa=192.168.2.120:8080/
bbb=192.168.2.130:8080/
ccc=192.168.2.140:8380/
```

My Html file which I got from get request on my server with aaa as a user.

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="UI">

<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

 <title>UI</title>

 <link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link type="text/css" href="css/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- custom css files -->
 <link type="text/css" href="css/components.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link type="text/css" href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link type="text/css" href="css/views.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link type="text/css" href="css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- Icons/Fonts -->
 <link type="text/css" href="fonts/md-icons/md-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
 <link type="text/css" href="css/roboto-fontface.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

</head>

<body ng-controller="BodyController">
 <div id="authentication" data-access-token="{{ACCESS_TOKEN}}"></div>
 <div ng-include="'partials/include.extension.html'"></div>
 <nav class="menu slide-menu-left" ng-controller="NavController">
  <div class="top clickable" ng-click="navigateToRoot()">
   <img id="logo" alt="Logo" src="img/logo.png" />
   <h1 class="title">App</h1>
  </div>
  <ul>
   <li ng-class="{active: isActive('control'), hidden: isHidden('control')}">
    <a href="#control">
     <span class="icon md-icon-dashboard"></span> Control</a>
   </li>
   <li ng-class="{active: isActive('inbox')}">
    <a href="#inbox" class="clickable">
     <span class="icon md-icon-add-circle-outline"></span> Inbox
     <span ng-show="getNumberOfNewDiscoveryResults() > 0" class="badge">{{getNumberOfNewDiscoveryResults()}}</span>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li ng-class="{active: isActive('configuration'), hidden: isHidden('configuration')}">
    <a ng-click="open('configuration')" class="clickable">
     <span class="icon md-icon-settings"></span> Configuration</a>
    <ul ng-show="isActive('configuration')">
     <li ng-class="{active: isSubActive('bindings')}"><a href="#configuration/bindings">Bindings</a></li>
     <li ng-class="{active: isSubActive('services')}"><a href="#configuration/services">Services</a></li>
     <li ng-class="{active: isSubActive('groups'), hidden: isHidden('groups')}"><a href="#configuration/groups">Groups</a></li>
     <li ng-class="{active: isSubActive('things')}"><a href="#configuration/things">Things</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li ng-class="{active: isActive('extensions'), hidden: isHidden('extensions')}">
    <a href="#extensions">
     <span class="icon md-icon-extension"></span>
     Extensions</a>
   </li>
   <li ng-class="{active: isActive('rules'), hidden: isHidden('rules')}">
    <a href="#rules">
     <span class="icon md-icon-movie-creation"></span>
     Rules</a>
   </li>
   <li ng-class="{active: isActive('preferences'), hidden: isHidden('preferences')}">
    <a href="#preferences">
     <span class="icon md-icon-brightness-medium"></span>
     Preferences</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="bottom">
   <span>UI</span>
  </div>
 </nav>

 <div id="wrapper">
  <header>
   <a href="#" class="open-menu">&#x2261;</a>
   <div class="title">
    <h1>
     {{title}}
     <span ng-repeat="subtitle in subtitles" class="subtitle">
      <span class="chevron md-icon-chevron-right"></span> {{subtitle}}</span>
    </h1>
   </div>
  </header>

  <ng-view autoscroll="true"></ng-view>

  <footer> </footer>
 </div>

 <!-- lib js files -->
 <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/angular-bundle.min.js"></script>


 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <!-- TODO: Create custom variant to save space -->
 <script src="js/tinycolor.js"></script>
 <script src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

 <!-- TODO: Use angularized version? -->
 <script src="js/sprintf.min.js"></script>

 <!-- custom js files -->
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 <script src="js/constants.js"></script>
 <script src="js/services.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/controllers.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/extensions.js"></script>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
 <script src="js/shared.properties.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, because it is the bit and pieces from different classes, I just wanted to give an over all idea what all code is involved in it. It will be difficult to write the entire code with different files/classes involved.